# Connecting to host by SSH client in Linux by proxy

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy

I am really struggling with this.

> My host (A) is behind a proxy/firewall (PF) and needs to connect to
>   host H.

The proxy has HTTP/FTP/SOCK proxy configured and I have no issue to configure in web browser, wget etc.

But when I use...

```
ssh H //to connect my host
```

I have no success to pass over the proxy. It seems to try to connect directly instead of going via the PF.

I am using Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this a duplicate of this other question?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/49664/ssh-over-socks-proxy-without-username-or-password

The solution presented in that entry is:

> You could use ssh under tsocks, or another SOCKS wrapper. Or use ssh's ProxyCommand in conjunction with socat or nc -X:
>
> ```
> ssh -o ProxyCommand='socat - socks:B:%h:21,socksport=1080' C
> ```